# How to open two instances of gimp?

Tags: gimp

I'm looking for a way to open two instances of Gimp 2.10.22. I know you can toggle off "Single-Window Mode" but I don't want to detach the sidebars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [user manual](https://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/gimp-fire-up.html) states that you can use the flag **-n** to run multiple instances of GIMP.

Assuming your OS is Windows, you can simply start the first instance of GIMP and use  <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the run dialog, putting the path of GIMP followed by **-n**, e.g.:

```
"C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\gimp-2.10.exe" -n
```

This opens another instance of GIMP:

[image: Multiple instances of GIMP]

If you want to open systematically GIMP in a new instance, you can add the flag **-n** on the GIMP shortcut in start menu (or in desktop or in the taskbar or wherever).

Be aware that this is more memory consuming for your system.

Answer (score 1):

"Two instances" and "Multiple windows" are two different things.

If you use "Multiple windows", there is still one single Gimp process, so in the UI, changes are common to all images: current FG/BG colors, active tool, etc...

You can use two instances (start Gimp with a `-n` parameter: `gimp -n` in a terminal window, or edit/duplicate your Gimp shortcut to add it), but in this case you have two Gimp processes that ignore each other and changes in the UIs will be kept distinct. Also, when you will close their UIs, the one with last UI closed will overwrite all the configuration elements saved by the other one, so this option is best used with other options that keep separate Gimp profiles as well.

Comment: Can't check both as I think both are correct. Suffice to say I have it working. Thanks -